How to measure the frequency at which neutrinos oscillate?
I just watched this video about detecting neutrinos for measuring neutrino oscillations. The experimental setup is basically as follows:

Generate muon neutrinos from high energy protons colliding with fixed graphite target (via a series of processes).
Those neutrinos will travel to a tank filled with liquid Argon.
The weak interaction of neutrinos with the Argon atoms causes creation of charged particles whose presence can then be measured.

It seems that the type of particles created in the interaction of the neutrinos with the Argon atoms seems to depend on the neutrino flavor. So I can understand that this allows to measure the rate of conversion from one flavor to another. However, in the video they also say that knowing the distance between the neutrino source and the detector would allow them to determine how fast these oscillations occur. This I don't understand. To me it seems that the frequency of these neutrino oscillations can only be measured across the length of the detector (i.e., the Argon tank) but anything that happens in between the source and the target is unknown (i.e., the neutrinos could have completed $n+x$ oscillation periods and all that can be measured at the tank is the fraction $x<1$ but not the integer number $n$). Am I missing something here?

Maybe try here Neutrino Oscillations.  It's not important to be at exactly two "nodes."
